# sqlite create column with value 1 if condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table (T1) that looks as follows:

```
user   fruit
A      orange
A      banana
B      cherry
B      banana
C      grape
```

Where the set of fruits consists of orange, banana, cherry, and grape.

Then, I have a second table (T2) listing all the users, all the possible fruits like this:

```
user   fruit
A      orange
A      banana
A      cherry
A      grape
B      orange
B      banana
```

My goal is to create a new column `is_orange` on the second table with value `1` if that row's `fruit` is `orange`. Like this:

```
user   fruit   is_orange
A      orange      1
A      banana      0
A      cherry      0
A      grape       0
B      orange      1
B      banana      0
```

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
    SELECT *,
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM T1 AS t1
                WHERE t1.user = T2.user AND t1.fruit = T2.fruit
            )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS is_orange
     FROM T2
```

The query works and it does what I want. However, it is pretty slow, and in my opinion, a bit hard to understand.

Is there an alternate way to achieve the same result using a faster and "cleaner" approach?

Comment: Your query does not search for rows where fruit = 'orange'. So how does it work? Also can you explain why you need T1 for this requirement?

Comment: I'll fix the query. In reality, I was obfuscating the real values so I did a mistake in the replacement.

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't that clear. T1 shows the fruits the user own, while T2 list all the possible fruits the user might own.

Comment: For this sample data your query does not return the results that you posted: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnnyghVcQdn3JAgd1Y4ZbQ/0

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to create a new column is_orange on the second table with value 1 if that row's fruit is orange. Like this:

I don't see what `table` has to do with this question.  Hence:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when fruit = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end) as is_orange
from t2;
```